# C++ template: cannot call my function from main.cpp

Tags: c++, function, templates, vector

This question may get thrown out but I've been searching and searching for help on this.  I am a total beginner.. OK: I have a template class with a function that adds two vectors and outputs to a 3rd vector. I need to call if from my main program. Here is my template (very simple).

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class polyClass {
public:
    //position 0 always constant, pos1 x^1, pos2 x^2
    vector<T> a;
    vector<T> b;
    vector<T> result;

    int addVectors(T& a, T& b, T& result) {

        for (vector<T> i = a[i].begin; i != a[i].end(); i++) {

            result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            return result;

        }
    }
};
```

I need to call the addVectors function from my main program. And I keep getting the message that I did not declare 'a', 'b', and 'result' in this scope.I am going on 3 hours with this and could really use some help. Here is my main program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#include "PolynomMult_Add.h"

int main() {

    polyClass<int> newPolyClass;
    newPolyClass.a = {3, 4, 2};
    newPolyClass.b = {3, 3, 1};
    newPolyClass.result = {};

    newPolyClass.addVectors(a, b, result);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several issues here. Why do you need to declare a class? Do you mean to declare a templated function instead? The `a`, `b`, `result` members of the class aren't serving any purpose (since you are passing the vectors are arguments to `addVectors`). The way that you are iterating over the vectors inside of `addVectors` is not quite right. You should read about iterators and iteration over containers. Specifically, you want to declare the loop index `i` to be of type `vector<T>::iterator` rather than `vector<T>`.

Comment: [this](https://ideone.com/7cCoGR) is prob. more what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting undeclared variables because you need to use newPolyClass.a, newPolyClass.b, newPolyClass.result instead of a, b and resullt. Here is corrected code.

```
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class polyClass {
public:
    //position 0 always constant, pos1 x^1, pos2 x^2
    vector<T> a;
    vector<T> b;
    vector<T> result;

    vector<T> addVectors(vector<T> & a, vector<T> & b, vector <T> & result) {

        for (auto i = a.begin(), j = b.begin(); i != a.end() && j != b.end(); i++, j++) {

            result.push_back (*i + *j);

        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

```
int main() {

    polyClass<int> newPolyClass;
    newPolyClass.a = {3, 4, 2};
    newPolyClass.b = {3, 3, 1};
    newPolyClass.result = {};

    newPolyClass.addVectors(newPolyClass.a, newPolyClass.b, newPolyClass.result);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was a huge leg up @Dhruv Sehgal